# How to calculate proportion using survey package?

Tags: r, survey

This is just a very simple question but I just cant find the right function to use from the web and books.

this is an example I got from one of the post here.

```
df <- data.frame(sex = c('F', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'F'),
             married = c(1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1),
             pens = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0),
             weight = c(1.12, 0.55, 1.1, 0.6, 0.23, 0.23, 0.66, 0.67))

d.s <- svydesign(ids=~1, data=df, weights=~weight)
```

I want to calculate the percentage variables such as married and calculate the standard error too?

also I want to do crosstab of married and pens and get the standard error of the resulting proportion?

how do i do that?

i tried svymean but it would treat the numeric values as integers instead of factors.

Comment: `d.s <- update( d.s , married = factor( married ) ) ; svymean( ~ married , d.s )`

Comment: The answer I want to accept is from Anthony Damico. How do I accept it as an answer when it is just a comment?

Comment: Just commenting to see if @AnthonyDamico would like to post his comment as an answer. It is the most straightforward alternative to calculate dispersion measures for proportions with `survey`.

Answer (score 6):

use `svytable`

```
summary(d.s)
svytable(~married+pens, d.s)
svytable(married~pens, d.s)
svytable(married~., d.s) #with all variable
```

Comment: @s.brunei: Thanks! but how do I add the the standard errors?

Answer (score 5):

On approach is using `interaction` in your formula with `svymean` or `svytotal`.

This should give you proportions of responses for each category as well as standard errors.

```
svymean(~interaction(married, pens), d.s.)
```

This should give you frequencies for each category as well as standard errors.

```
svytotal(~interaction(married, pens), d.s.)
```

Comment: How would I get confidence intervals around the proportions with "interaction", @Peter Miksza? Is there a built-in function or would I have to do it by hand? Not seeing anything in the documentation.

Comment: You can use confint() or svyciprop() is more accurate in some conditions. The UCLA site has some nice discussion of how to use these:  
https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/seminars/survey-data-analysis-with-r/#:~:text=We%20can%20use%20the%20confint,confidence%20interval%20around%20this%20mean.&text=However%2C%20comment%20on%20page%2070of,supplied%20for%20the%20method%20argument.

Answer (score 5):

Use `prop.table` along with `svy.table`:

```
prop.table(svytable((~married, pens),d.s), margin=1)

#margin=1 will give you column percentages
```

Comment: margin = 1 seems to actually give row percentages. Also, the "formula" argument is incorrectly specified. This code works for me, using the above df and design object

prop.table(svytable(~married+pens,d.s), margin=1)

Comment: How do you get confidence intervals for the row percentages, @Cody Melcher?